# Sigma algebra generated by product of sets = sigma algebra generated by the product of the sigma algebras generated by the sets under this condition?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

Suppose that $X, Y$ are given non empty sets. Let $C, D$ be collection of subsets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Suppose that there exists sequences $\{C_n\}$ (of elements of $C$) and $\{D_n\}$ (of elements of $D$) such that $\cup_n C_n= X, \cup_n D_n=Y$. Then,  $M(C\times D)=M(C)\otimes M(D)$, where $M$('set') means "$\sigma$ algebra generated by the set." $M(C)\otimes M(D)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $M(C)\times M(D)$.

I tried to prove it like this:

It is clear that $M(C\times D)\subset M(C)\otimes M(D)$. For containment in the other direction, define

$\scr E:$$=\{E\in M(C)\otimes M(D): E\in M(C\times D)\}$.

$\scr E$ is non empty as it contains $\emptyset$ and $X\times Y$.

**$\scr E$ is an algebra:**  For any $E_1, E_2\in \scr E$, $E_1\cup E_2\in \scr E$ and $E_1^c\in \scr E$.

**$\scr E$ is a monotone class.** So if it is shown that $\scr E$ contains all $A\times B, A\in M(C), B\in M(D)$, then we are done. But I'm not sure how to go from here and how to use $\cup_n C_n=C, \cup_n D_n=D$? Any hints on this please?

Comment: Isn't $\mathcal{C}$ already an $\sigma$-algebra? If$ E_n\in\mathcal{C}$ then $\bigcup_n\in M(C)\otimes M(D)$ (being a $\sigma$-algebra) also $\bigcup_nE_n$ for $E_n\in M(C\times D)$ which is a $\sigma$-algebra. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I think the statement does not hold in general. Take two topological spaces ($X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$  which are not separable. Let $C=\tau_X$ and $D=\tau_Y$. $C$ and $D$ satisfy the conditions of your positing; however $\sigma(\tau_Y)\otimes\sigma(\tau_Y)\neq\sigma(\tau_X\times \tau_Y)$

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Thanks a lot for the comments. $\scr E$ being a sigma algebra is fruitful if it is shown that it contains all rectangles (i.e., $A\times B, A\in M(C), B\in M(D))$.

Comment: About the second comment: I don't yet know enough topology to understand the comment. But is the sequence condition being satisfied in this example?

Comment: I fixed an $A\in C$, then tried to prove that $A\times M(D)\subset M(C\times D)$. Then proving that $M(C)\times M(D)\subset M(C\times M(D))$ should complete the solution but I got stuck at showing closed under complements.

Comment: Like I said, the result is not true in general. If $C$ and $D$ are say countable and a $\pi$-system, then sure. The example I mentioned earlier is about when the product of Borel $\sigma$-algebras coincides with the Borel sigma-algebra in the product. When the topologies are too large, the answer in the negative. The book of D. Cohn on Measure theory has a rather nice treatment of this. It has to do with the measurability of the diagonal.

Comment: Yes the condition is satisfied, take $C_n=X$ for example.